# Return Multiple Out and Return Image value in C# using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

How to return image from Stored procedure using Dapper in C#?

I have a stored procedure with multiple out's and a return value. I want to read the return type in C#

PFB the Code and Stored procedure. Please suggest me how to resolve this.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_Sessions
    @id nvarchar(80),  
    @IsLocked  bit OUTPUT,  
    @LockAge    int OUTPUT

AS  
    DECLARE @textptr AS varbinary(16)  
    DECLARE @length AS int  
    DECLARE @now AS datetime  
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE() 
-- Update Query Begins not complete Query example --

@textptr = CASE IsLocked  
            WHEN 0 THEN TEXTPTR(State)  
            ELSE NULL  
            END
        @length = CASE IsLocked  
            WHEN 0 THEN DATALENGTH(State)  
            ELSE NULL  
            END

-- Update Query Ends--

    IF @length IS NOT NULL BEGIN  
        READTEXT dbo.commons.State @textptr 0 @length  
    END  

    RETURN 0
```

C# Code:

```cs
DynamicParameters dp = new DynamicParameters();
dp.Add("@Id", Id);
dp.Add("@IsLocked", dbType: DbType.Boolean, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
dp.Add("@LockAge", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
dp.Add("ReturnValue", dbType: DbType.Object, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

connection.Query<byte>("Exclusive", dp, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

isLocked = dp.Get<bool>("@IsLocked");
lockAge = dp.Get<int>("@LockAge");

var returnvalue = dp.Get<object>("ReturnValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Define a class named 'ResultClass' and include the fields of the procedures as its properties(you can use byte[] type for the image field).then you can query all fields of the  table and put the result into an instance of the resultClass,as follow:

```
var result = db.Query<ResultClass>("SELECT * from procedure_Sessions") ;
```